# Tableau Command Line - Refresh datasource

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau Workbook which connects to server-side data source.  Researching online it seems the accepted way to refresh this is something like
`tabcmd refreshextracts -–datasource “Number of Goals”`.

My datasource is named "aggregated usage table".  I have tried basically copying what I saw online, using 
`tabcmd refreshextracts -–datasource “aggregated usage table”`, and receive the error message "*** Item not found".  Clearly I am not correctly identifying my data source.

Can someone help me determine the correct syntax for this?

The O/E is Linux.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Longshot**, but something looks off about your dashes...

When I copy yours vs mine:

```
-– vs --
```

When I put yours into word and enlarge they look even weirder. Sometimes this can happen if copying and pasting from the web to import into your script.

Try copying and pasting my command and see if it works:

```
tabcmd refreshextracts --datasource “aggregated usage table”
```

Comment: Also, are you missing any capitalizations in your datasource name?